# After successfully running the docker container, Docker exec command is not doing anything

Tags: docker, docker-exec

Running `exec` command is returning random testlike ^[[50;5R. When running the same commands in windows, it just stuck and I am not able to type anything. Need to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> to exit it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run docker exec -it container_name/id command.
ex: `docker exec -it ubuntu /bin/bash`
The i allows you to have interaction/input within the container and the t allows you to open a tty console to the container.

Comment: Thanks. By mistake I was giving only -t while running docker exec